# MoveToElement when element is just onscreen

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

When using this code to bring an element into the browser view, it works most of the time.

```
    protected void MakeVisible(IWebElement link, bool always)
    {
        var actions = new Actions(this.Driver);
        actions.MoveToElement(link).Perform();
        ...
```

However, when the element is *just* (say a button that is 50% there) on screen, it doesn't, but it isn't onscreen enough to register for a click event.

[image]

(The bottom of the snip is the bottom of the browser viewport)

How can I handle this edge case?

This was encountered using the FireFox driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen this behavior before. Generally when I click on an element, if it's offscreen, the viewport (automatically) is scrolled so that it's visible and it is clicked. I'll give you my best guess and hopefully it will give you some ideas that you can investigate and hopefully solve the problem.

So I think the issue is that `.MoveToElement()` moves to the center of the element. If the center of the element in question is on the page but is not able to be clicked because it's not fully visible, then it seems like a solution is to make sure the entire element is on the page. One way I can think of to do this is to use [`MoveToElement(IWebElement, Int32, Int32)`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions_Actions_MoveToElement_1.htm). The offsets are from the top-left corner of the element. If you use this to move to the top-left and then the bottom-right, that combination should fully display the element then it can be clicked. The top-left would be 0,0 and the bottom right would be found using [`IWebElement.Size`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Size.htm) to get the width and height of the element.

A function would look something like this

```
public void ShowElement(IWebElement e)
{
    Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
    action.MoveToElement(e, 0, 0).MoveToElement(e, e.Size.Width, e.Size.Height).Build().Perform();
}
```